# Redirect non-www to www over SSL in apache not working

Tags: ssl, apache2, 301-redirect

My virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

#Redirect non-https or non-www to https://www...
RewriteEngine On
#NOT TESTING HTTPS REDIRECTION FOR NOW
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

The conf file for SSl is the default one by letsencrypt.

My tests so far, first 3 results are expected, last is not

```
decimoseptimo@ubuntu-512mb-sfo2-1:~$ curl -I http://example.com                                                 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.example.com/
```

301

```
decimoseptimo@ubuntu-512mb-sfo2-1:~$ curl -I http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

OK

```
decimoseptimo@ubuntu-512mb-sfo2-1:~$ curl -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

OK

```
decimoseptimo@ubuntu-512mb-sfo2-1:~$ curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

OK

Seems www redirection is not occuring over SSL! no idea why, apache was restarted since last configuration editing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not working because your rewrite rules are only in `<VirtualHost *:80>`.  SSL is not running on port 80.

Comment: I splitted the conditions in both vhosts and it worked. Would the alternative be `<VirtualHost *:*>` Any with issues that? or what other option would there be

Comment: Wouldn't want to to a combined one cuz the 443 has to have the certificate config

Comment: So no alternatives other than two directives, I'm ok with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two tests would match the 443 VirtualHost. You have not included that in the question, but we can assume that there is not a matching RewriteCond/Rule pair in the 443 VirtualHost.

Comment: Cool, in splitted the conditions to both vthosts and it and worked.